# Using EmailField instead of ChoiceField with forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have classified and email model:

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class Classified(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    contact_email = models.ForeignKey(EmailAddress)
```

In forms, i want users to use regular emailfield to input email address. If address not found create and save it to database. Here what i did to archive this:

```
class CreateClassifiedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contact_email = EmailField(label=_('Contact Email'))

    class Meta:
        model = Classified
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'contact_email',
                  'contact_email_visible', 'contact_email_proxied', 'desc']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cleaned_data['contact_email'] = \
            EmailAddress.objects.get_or_create(
                address=self.cleaned_data['contact_email'])[0]
        clsfd = Classified(**self.cleaned_data)
        clsfd.save()
        return clsfd
```

But when i call is_valid() method of this form, i get error:

```
Cannot assign "u'foo@foo.com'": "Classified.contact_email" must be a "EmailAddress" instance.
```

I think is_valid method tries to instantiate object from given fields and fails. What is best practice to archive the thing i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing that in `save` at all. Instead, override `clean_contact_email` to just return the EmailAddress from get_or_create, and remove the save definition altogether.